# Double Pendulum - equation of angle with respect to time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, chaos-theory, complex-systems, coupled-oscillators

First of all I am in grade 12, last year of my IB diploma programme. I'm familiar with derivatives and integrals but nothing as complex as these Lagrangians, Hamiltonians or other university-level mathematical principles.

I'm going to do a simulation in C#, then write an essay analysing basic stuff like potential and kinetic energy. However the only variable I have control over is time, so I need to find an equation of angle with respect to time.

For single pendulum the equation was extremely easy and now I think I am looking in wrong direction to get my answer for the double pendulum.

Comment: There will certainly be $2$ angles and as you can see from Eqs.(15)-(16) of https://diego.assencio.com/?index=1500c66ae7ab27bb0106467c68feebc6 the equations of motion are quite complicated.  What exactly are you asking?  How to obtain the EOM, how to solve them...?

Comment: Before I started working on double pendulum I did some simulations for single pendulum and there I had equation for Theta with only one variable, time. I was able to write a loop with t += 0.05 and everything worked.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pend.html#c3

Comment: I don’t want to sound discouraging but the EOM for the two angles are given in (15)-(16) in the link above.   Can you use those to formulate a conceptual question?   Note the panel on the right where related questions are listed and some of them might be useful.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Actually, Eqs (15)-(16) are basically worthless. You should be directing OP to Eqs (27)-(28), since *those* are what you need to use to solve the double pendulum numerically.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes and at the bottom there is even a link to python code if this is all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the first section on the [relevant Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is the statement (emphasis mine)

> These last four equations are explicit formulae for the time evolution of the system given its current state. **It is not possible to go further and integrate these equations analytically**, to get formulae for $θ_1$ and $θ_2$ as functions of time. It is, however, possible to perform this integration numerically using the Runge Kutta method or similar techniques.

where the referenced 4 equations describe the time evolution of $\theta_i$ and $p_{\theta_i}$ for $i=1,2$. So the equation you are looking for simply *does not exist*, you *must* use numerical integration to track the evolution of the two bobs.

Matplotlib (a Python package for plotting) uses the double pendulum [as an example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html) for using the plotting package (and references a C code as well), you probably could use that as a starting point for your own work.